# Running a C file as windows service

Tags: c, windows

Is there anyway you can run an executable C file immediately after windows gets restarted?
For instance i have the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch;

   printf("Do you want to shutdown your computer now (y/n)\n");
   scanf("%c", &ch);

   if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
      system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown -s");

   return 0;
}
```

and I want this code to get immediately executed when windows start

Comment: `system()` under windows uses the command processor (CMD), which is not available to be run during the boot process.    More generally, programs that run as windows services must use windows-specific techniques so they can be loaded and controlled by the Service Control Manager (SCM).   These techniques are not part of standard C.

Comment: Microsoft has a pretty good [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476(v=vs.85).aspx) of how to make a proper service for windows

Comment: Not to be too much of a pedant but Windows can't run a C file.  Windows can, however, run a C file that has been compiled into an executable.

Comment: You can register your program in the registry under blabla\CurrentVersion\Run - through API calls. And then you can shut down the computer through another API call. No need to make a service. And calling `system()` is probably not a good idea, use Windows API.

Comment: @lundin I want everything to be done automatically.

Comment: @YoussefSakuragi Yeah well, this question is a bit too broad since it involves registry access and various APIs. It would be better if you posted your attempts so far. And obviously it shouldn't be some console crap in the year 2017.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this through a C program? Why not a simple bat file maybe?

Comment: @lundin I have already fixed it, jeff 's answer was the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you're looking for is to put it in the registry under `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run`.  That will cause it to run every time Windows starts up.  Just add a REG_SZ key (call it whatever you want) and set its value to the path to the executable for your program.

If you really want to create a Windows service (I don't think you do), then check out [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476(v=vs.85).aspx) for an example of how to create one.  That's overkill for what you want to do here, though - if all you want to do is run a program at startup, the registry key is the way to go.

Shutting down the system at startup seems like a weird thing to want to do...

Comment: I cant seem to find `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run` on my laptop.

Comment: HKLM is short for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: I found it, I dont want to immediately want to shutdown the system, I want to do it after 20 minutes. The above code was a mere example.

Comment: @YoussefSakuragi - From your original post:  `I want this code to get immediately executed when windows start`

Comment: @KevinDTimm u are quite the pedant indeed, and meh its just as i said, that code is an example, i forgot to put in the 20 min sleep.